# PHP string not updating mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, string

Environment: 
PHP 7, mySQL, phpMyAdmin, localhost, MAMP, Mac

## Issue:

I am parsing some html text to a mySQL database on my localhost and the string does not seem to update the table as planned.

I tested the code and was able to narrow down the problem root as the string contained in a variable that I am trying to then update in mySQL table.

I tested the variable and the query syntax by replacing the string within the variable manually as 'Test test test' and this loaded successfully when I ran the code.

I also tried changing the mySQL table structure from 'text' to 'long text' even though the string was clearly short enough to fit in a text field but this did not help.

I am fairly convinced the issue is with the string itself and possibly the table/ field structure.

It is also worth mentioning that the query update worked with other strings through this code and it only fails in some cases (although quite often)

## What I am asking

At this point and after trying a few things and researching for info, I am a little stuck as to what the issue could be so any advice would be useful if you have encountered this issue before.
Below is a bit more info about the code and the string.

## Info

Here is the string:

```
$Definition = verb (used without object) , abode or abided, abiding. 1. to remain; continue; stay: abide with me. 2. to have one's abode; dwell; reside: to abide in a small scottish village. 3. to continue in a particular condition, attitude, relationship, etc.; last. verb (used with object) , abode or abided, abiding. 4. to put up with; tolerate; stand: i can't abide dishonesty! 5. to endure, sustain, or withstand without yielding or submitting: to abide a vigorous onslaught. 6. to wait for; await: to abide the coming of the lord. 7. to accept without opposition or question: to abide the verdict of the judges. 8. to pay the price or penalty of; suffer for. verb phrases 9. abide by, to act in accord with. to submit to; agree to: to abide by the court's decision. to remain steadfast or faithful to; keep: if you make a promise, abide by it.;
```

Code:

```
        $Definition = implode('', $InterArray); //I also tested the array to string conversion works fine
        //$Definition = 'Test test test'; I tested this and it worked
        $Definition = (string) $Definition;

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","myDB");              
        $sql="INSERT INTO myTable (DEFINITION) VALUES('".$Definition."');";             
        $conn->query($sql);
```

SQL table:
DEFINITION, Type: Long text, Collation: latin_swedish_ci, Default: none

Comment: You should `escape` the string.

Comment: @SougataBose The string is already being quoted, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The string contains `'`s and OP using `'` only.

Comment: being quoted is not enough. there are characters that will be treated differently in mysql. like ';'. you need to escape them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The string is escaped in the query but not at the declaration.

Comment: @SougataBose Oops, I was only looking at the query, yes, you're right.

Comment: Escaping is good, but you should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to truly protect you against SQL injections, and other issues just like yours.

Comment: Am I blind or something? Where are you guys seeing the string being escaped?

Comment: thanks all, that was the issue; all working now. I am still puzzled about why it worked with some strings and not others??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

to avoid any confusion, it's preferable to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` than to escape the string manually. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function takes care of the escaping itself.

according to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php):

"This function is used to create a legal SQL string that you can use in an SQL statement. The given string is encoded to an escaped SQL string, taking into account the current character set of the connection."

as Magnus said, Prepared Statement is always the best choice. you can never be too sure about the security of your aplication.

Comment: The question is using mysqli, not mysql_* functions

Comment: 1. He's using MySQLi, not MySQL. 2. It's preferred to use Prepared Statements, not `mysql/mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Why is PDO the best? How is PDO more secure than MySQLi?

Comment: I never said PDO. I said Prepared Statements, which works well with MySQLi, as well.

Comment: @MridulKashyap - Like I said in my comment, you can use Prepared Statements with MySQLi as well, so your comment doesn't really make any sense as an answer to Mike's question. I would appreciate if you updated your answer with what I actually said.

Comment: @Mike consider it like this, you can add a string taken from a user to your own string, and show it like they were always connected seamlessly. that's not the case with mysqli though, you want to send the value of the variable as it is, since if that variable, if somehow updated your sql string, it can have bad consequences. Prepared Statement makes sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson updated. i still had mysql in my head for some reason. apologies.

Comment: @MridulKashyap Your comment is extremely confusing to read and doesn't make much sense. I know what prepared statements are. You had initially said that the OP should use PDO since that is "better". If you already have your program written in MySQLi, switching PDO, unless you have a [very specific need to do so based on the features available in each API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), is probably pointless. Using both PDO and MySQLi can be either secure or insecure and neither is more secure than the other. It depends on your implementation of each that determines it.

Comment: @MridulKashyap And I don't know why in your answer you recommend using `mysqli_real_escape_string` when you also say that that's not the best choice. If that's not the best choice, don't recommend it.

Comment: @Mike because OP is not looking for securing his app. his original question is about escaping the string so it works in mysql. but since Prepared statement is a better choice, i deemed it was worth mentioning it. He'd switch to Prepared Statement if he wants. I think i gave a complete answer.